# Does iOS block a URL if we couldn't connect to the URL for 'n' times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, networking

Please look at this scenario

1. The app access a URL. The server is down so the request times out.
2. This process is repeated for 'n' times.
3. The server is up and running now. But inside the app the URL returns the same result.
4. Tries in Safari and no response but seems to work fine in other devices.
5. The app is restarted and no use.
6. The device is restarted and the URL start working fine.

Does the iOS blocks a URL if it couldn't be accessed for 'n' times? And the restart resets everything?

Comment: URLs and the results of URL requests can be cached. Read Apple's documentation how to download a URL without caching.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @gnasher729 try this and see if it works

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:timeOut];
```

Comment: I am already using this. Once the URL is blocked even restarting the app doesn't help it. Restarting the device helps.